# Unable to connect to Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm working on Selenium and I currently have a hub connected to two vms running linux with all the browsers.

I was able to launch browsers until suddenly it just stopped . Firefox or any of the other browsers don't launch. I get the following error.

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

I am running Selenium-server-standalone 2.26 with firefox 16.0.2 .

Please help.

Comment: This is the  error I get :                                    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

Command duration or timeout: 45.88 seconds
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.2', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: 
 at

Comment: did u try checking restarting the selenium nodes ?

Answer (score 7):

Try running this before you start your Selenium server:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: @Amey Where? I use Scala to do this testing and have the same error. I'm using VNC so I guess I'll have to export accordingly :6 (right now), just need to now where should I do this export

Comment: @user247077 On your machine terminal. `DISPLAY` is essentially an environment variable which needs to be exported from the command line. The number is obtained when you start VNC.

Comment: @Amey I understand that (Thanks though!). I need to know where should I do this export. My vnc is at :6

Comment: You need to export it in the same bash environment from where you will initiate your tests. So if you are on mac, open a terminal, type `vncserver`, observe the display number(lets say its :6), then type `export DISPLAY=:6` on the terminal, *THEN* trigger your tests `scala [-cp scalatest-<version>.jar:...] org.scalatest.tools.Runner [arguments]`