# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException when starting Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I'm getting this error message while trying to initiate the `Firefox` browser:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   s":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false}

I am using `selenium 3.3.1` and `firefox 52`.

Comment: Show your browser config code

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your driver e.g. geckodriver is compatible with the installed version of Firefox.

There is a similar question here that might help you:
[Unable to connect to Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281568/unable-to-connect-to-firefox)

Comment: Do I need to use GeckoDriver?

Comment: You need to use a driver to bridge selenium to a browser, in Firefoxs case this a driver called geckodriver you can get it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Make sure your using selenium 3.3.1 as well when using gecko driver.

Comment: I'm using gecko version - v0.15

Comment: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
65 addons.xpi DEBUG Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0

Comment: Can you add your code you use to initialise the driver to your question?

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
 driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/");
 System.out.println("successfully opened the website");
 
 Thread.sleep(5);
 driver.quit();

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium) question has a good answer that may help you, you may need to set the desired capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting path for Gecko Driver
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<**geckodriver path**>")

Comment: I'm using selenium version 3.3.1

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe)
  
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Still there is **NotConnectedException**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use GeckoDriver for Firefox. This was not needed for the older versions of Selenium 2.x, but it's required with Selenium 3.x

You would need to download GeckoDriver based on if your FF browser is 32-bit or 64-bit. You would also need to provide GeckoDriver and FirefoxBirnary path. Sample code that you can use to launch browser -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

You can check this link for more info - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: Thanks @Anish Pillai. I tried following the steps and set up gecko but now still facing the issue unfortunately. org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
webNavigation","webRequest"]}}

Comment: And also when firefox browser is launched, there are two tabs open and on second tab I can see 'Skype' website launch.